# Pagination for a list of posts with custom_terms

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have code that gets all posts for a custom term, 
I want to apply pagination for that code.

```
<div> <?php

 $text = $_POST['text'];
 /*   echo ($text);  */ 
 $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1 );
 $posts = get_posts( $args );
 foreach($posts as $post) 
 {
    $custom_terms = get_the_terms($post->ID,'Characters');
    foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) 
    {
        if ( ($custom_term->name) == ($text) ) 
        {
        ?>          
            <div class="col-sm-2">
            <article class="item">
            <div class="article-inner">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="img-wrapper"><img class="img-100p latest-post-image" 
        src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('large'); ?>" alt="img"></div>
            <div class="article-info">
            <h4 class="entry-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><?php 
        //echo $countA ?><?php //echo $count_posts?><?php //echo $count%$st?></a>
            </h4>
            </div>
            </div>
            </article>
            </div>
        <?php

        }   
    }        
}

?>
</div>
```

I'm using plugin 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wck-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-creator/
to create that custom_terms on backend admin wordpress.

and try to use this code but when go to page number 2 no posts apperas

```
 <div>


    <?php 
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $count = 0; 
    $st = 15;
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1 );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    $stack = array(2005);
    $poststatus = array( 'publish' );
    $current_category = single_cat_title("", false);




    foreach($posts as $post) 
    {
        $custom_terms = get_the_terms($post->ID,'characters');
        foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) 
        {
            if ( (($custom_term->name) == ($text))   ) 
            {               
                $counter ++  ;
                array_push($stack,($post->ID) );
            }
        }   
    }        



     $args1 = array( 
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'post__in' => $stack,
    //'category_name'      => '',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 18,
    //'offset' => 5,
    'order_by' => 'date',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 5 ,

    );

  $wp_query  = new WP_Query( $args1 );
    $count_posts = $wp_query->post_count;
    if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : 
        while (  $wp_query->have_posts() ) : 
            $wp_query->the_post(); 
     $count++;
     if ($count%$st == 4) :
     $count = 1; 
    ?>
    <?php 
    endif;
    ?>      
        <div class="col-sm-4">
        <article class="item">
        <div class="article-inner">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="img-wrapper"><img class="img-100p latest-post-image" 
 src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('large'); ?>" alt="img"></div>
        <div class="article-info">
        <h4 class="entry-title">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h4>

        </div>
        </div>
        </article>
        </div><!--col-sm-4-->
<?php
 endwhile;
 //wp_reset_postdata();
 //wp_reset_query();
    //wp_reset_postdata();
 endif;

 ?>
```

@ManoharSingh

This is full template file

```
                    <?php
                    /**
                    <?php /* Template Name: C1 
                     *
                     * Used to display archive-type pages if nothing more specific matches a query.
                     * For example, puts together date-based pages if no date.php file exists.
                     *
                     * If you'd like to further customize these archive views, you may create a
                     * new template file for each one. For example, tag.php (Tag archives),
                     * category.php (Category archives), author.php (Author archives), etc.
                     *
                     * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
                     *
                     * @package Primer
                     * @since 1.0.0
                     */
                    get_header(); 



                      $temp = $wp_query; 
                     // $wp_query = null; 
                      $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
                      $wp_query->query('showposts=6&post_type=post_type_name'.'&paged='.$paged); 

                      while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
                    ?>


                    <div>

                    <?php

                    $text = $_POST['text'];
                    /*   echo ($text);  */ 
                        $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1 );
                        $posts = get_posts( $args );
                        foreach($posts as $post) 
                        {
                            $custom_terms = get_the_terms($post->ID,'characters');
                            foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) 
                            {
                                if ( ($custom_term->name) == ($text) ) 
                                {
                                ?>          
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <article class="item">
                                    <div class="article-inner">
                                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                                    <div class="img-wrapper"><img class="img-100p latest-post-image" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('large'); ?>" alt="img"></div>
                                    <div class="article-info">
                                    <h4 class="entry-title">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><?php //echo $countA ?><?php //echo $count_posts?><?php //echo $count%$st?></a>
                                    </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </article>
                                    </div>
                                <?php

                                }   
                            }        
                        }

                    ?>





                        </div>



                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                        <section class="all-pagination">
                        <div class="container">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-md-12 in-pagination">
                        <ul class="pagination">

                        <?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $wp_query ) ); ?>
                            <?php //if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $wp_query ) ); } ?>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </section>
                          <?php  ?>
                    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
<?php 
  $temp = $wp_query; 
  $wp_query = null; 
  $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
  $wp_query->query('showposts=6&post_type=post_type_name'.'&paged='.$paged); 

  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
?>

  <!-- LOOP: Usual Post Template Stuff Here-->

<?php endwhile; ?>

<nav>
    <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer') ?>
    <?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;') ?>
</nav>
```

And you can try this plugin for pagination 'https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/'

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it gives empty page.

Comment: echo something inside the while loop like post titles or contents and try. in post_type_name change your post type name.